# How to remove zero values from arrays in dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a dictionary containing 2d arrays:

```
dict = {
    "a": np.array([[0, 2, 3], [4, 0, 6]]),
    "b": np.array([[1, 0, 3], [4, 5, 0]]),
    "c": np.array([[1, 2, 0], [0, 5, 6]])}
```

And I want to remove zero values from each array in that dictionary.
The output I want to get should look like this:

```
dict = {
    "a": np.array([[2, 3], [4, 6]]),
    "b": np.array([[1, 3], [4, 5]]),
    "c": np.array([[1, 2], [5, 6]])}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{k: v for k, v in d.items() if v}
```

removing **False**, **[]**, **None** also